# The application window does not start

Tags: c#, winforms

I write in Visual Studio using Access. the application starts (sort of) and closes immediately, i.e. the application window does not appear. here is the code:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App_For_Test_Base
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Delphi-Projects\\UP.01.01.Khuraskin\\Project\\Test_Base.mdb;";
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Teacher";
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                try
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                        listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
                finally
                {
                    reader.Close(); // closing the database connection
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close(); // closing the database connection
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I do not know what I have to change in order for this form to appear

Comment: I tried to change the bit depth of the CPU from the CPU API to x86 and x64, but nothing worked

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Did you change the template code's ctor? Seems you are creating a Stackoverflow by recursively calling the constructor. (`new Form1()` called inside that very constructor)

Comment: Why didn't you start from the winforms default project template?

Comment: and what should I change. C# is complicated for me, so I don't really understand it.

Comment: about the mistake. no problems found

Comment: @Fildor I don't think there is a stack overflow here, as `Form1()` isn't **actually** called anywhere (or at least it doesn't seem to be). If it were to be called, then Horoshiy would probably indeed get a stackoverflow exception, but he didn't mention it

Comment: there were no exceptions or errors. the window simply does not display on the screen. it started, assembled, and so on, and just completed execution.

Comment: @Rafalon well, that was what caught my eye. But you are right, there probably is another problem outside the code shown.

Comment: Or: the problem may actually be that there is no other code...

Answer (score 3):

You should start from the default WinForms project template, it will include 2 classes, `Form1` and `Program`

[image]

This is the basic application layout for WinForms which includes the `Main` application entry point within `Program.cs` that in turn initializes an instance of the main form, by default named `Form1`. It then binds the Application lifetime to this form, so the application will end when the form is closed.

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Application.Run(new Form1());` is similar to your code, but it is *outside* of your `Form1` definition.

- This is important because in your code, the following logic would be executed:

  1. Create instance of `Form1()` by calling the constructor
  2. Start the Application lifetime environment
  3. Run the Application **AFTER** creating a ***NEW*** instance of `Form1`
  4. Do step 1 again
  5. Start a new application... step 2
  6. step 3
  7. step 1 again...

  ...
  This goes on infinitely until the application runs out of memory, resulting in a StackOverflow!

So you can't create a new instance of `Form1` inside of the constructor for `Form1`. That is why the standard program template for Winforms guides you to create a *static* class that encapsulates the whole application that loads your main form.
 
In `Form1.cs` this is the minimal code that you need:

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

You would then add your `Form1_Load` event handler to this class, but do not change the constructor.

---

When starting a new programming language, or new framework, it is often helpful to start with the basic implementation templates to help your understand the basic mechanics and expectations before starting from first principals. If you do start from first principals you should be following a step by step guide, this mistake you have made is a very easy one to diagnose if you step through the code line by line in your debugger, but until you understand how to do that it might be easier to start with code that you know works and slowly add new features so you can undo changes that break your logic.

Answer (score 2):

First off, heed @Chris Schallar advice.

My recommendation is to not place data operations in form load event as there are cases where a runtime exception gets swallowed. Instead place the code in form shown event.

Rather than a OleDbCommand and OleDbDataReader use [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) NuGet package.

Create a class which represents you data from the Access database table. Since I do not know your column names I improvised. Note the *.ToString* represents what will be shown in the ListBox.

```cs
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => FullName;
}
```

In the shown event a connection is made to the database followed by using Dapper to read the data, note Dapper opens and closes the connection for you.

If all goes as expected, I placed a button on the form to get the current teacher data.

```cs
using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App_For_Test_Base
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += Form1_Shown;
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Delphi-Projects\\UP.01.01.Khuraskin\\Project\\Test_Base.mdb;"))
            {
                try
                {
                    var teacherList = cn.Query<Teacher>("SELECT * FROM Teacher").ToList();
                    listBox1.DataSource = teacherList;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CurrentBookButton.Enabled = false;
                    MessageBox.Show($"Failed to read data\n{ex.Message}");
                }
            }
        }

        private void CurrentBookButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Teacher teacher = (Teacher)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show($@"{teacher.Id} {teacher.FullName}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normaaly if you let visual studio create a winforms project, the constructor of your main form doesn't have the statements:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Remove them, and check if your application starts.

If not, empty `Form1_Load`, because in that case the error will be there. Debug with a breakpoint to see if Form1_Load is started.

### You are executing a query

The statement `ExecuteNonQuery` is only used if you execute a SQL statement that doesn't return data. Your command "SELECT * FROM Teacher" does return data, hence you should not use ExecutNonQuery but only `ExecuteReader`

### Make sure that IDisposables are properly Disposed

class OleDbConnection and several other classes that you use implement IDisposable. You should Dispose all IDisposable objects.

It is good practice to surround every IDisposable with a `using` statement. This way the object is Disposed (hence also Closed) even after an exception.

```
const string dbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; ...";
const string sqlCommandText = "SELECT * FROM Teacher";

// Create and open the connection to the database:
using (var dbConnection = new OleDbConnection())
{
    dbConnection.ConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    dbConnection.Open();

    // Create and execute the SQL command:
    using (var dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = sqlCommandText;
        using (var dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // display the fetched data
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        // the end of this using will Dispose() the dbReader, even after exception
    }
    // the end of this using will Dispose() the dbCommand
}
// the end of this using will Dispose the dbConnection, which will Close it
```